# Win 7: Default gateway address keeps getting removed in static tcp/ipv4 settings

Tags: windows-7, networking, ip, gateway

Every couple of days my pc keeps getting limited connectivity to the internet. I can only access googe and a couple of social media sites.
I have found the cause and its because the default gateway address keeps getting erased from my static tcp/ip.v4 settings in my network connections although all my other settings, IP, subnet and DNS are there.

Unfortunately i cannot figure out what is causing this.
I have a PIA vpn that i rarely use but i cannot relate the connectivity issues with when i connect to the vpn.

Any ideas on where i should look?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Unidentified Network - Default Gateway address disappears on powerdown Solved - Windows 7 Help Forums](https://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/319188-unidentified-network-default-gateway-address-disappears-powerdown.html)?

Comment: Did everything described here, seems to work for now, will monitor report back in a couple of days. thanks!